# SQL Server charindex with declared variable

Tags: sql-server, variables, char

I have a simple problem with SQL SERVER `charindex` function.

```
DECLARE @VAR1 varchar
SET @VAR1 = 'abcdef'
PRINT CHARINDEX('c', @VAR1)
```

The above statement should print **3** but prints **0**. Why?

Comment: Because you didn't declare a length for your `varchar` variable, so it was truncated to a single character. You would see this if you do `PRINT @VAR1;`. Please see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When n (length) is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1.

---

Do it like this and your problem is solved:

```
DECLARE @VAR1 varchar(10)
SET @VAR1 = 'abcdef'
PRINT CHARINDEX('c', @VAR1)
```

---

For more info, check [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the answer and link. Also learnt this: 'When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.'

Comment: @Tim nice! Don't forget to always specify the length! :)